# Trouble enabling viewBindings (kotlin)

Tags: xml, kotlin, expandablelistview, android-viewbinding

I have not adhered to the Single Activity Schema and have multiple Activities in my application.
All examples I can find using expandableListView require bindings.

I have:

1.)

```
buildFeatures {
            viewBinding = true
        }
```

2.)
**The layout tag within my xml**

I have also tried using the include tag I found in some tutorial but

```
 val binding = ProfileActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

is not resolving to a binding.
Am I misinterpreting how to use this?
Any tips are appreciated

I should note that within MainActivity.kt attempting to assign MainActivityBinding does not work either.

Comment: What is the name of your XML file? The binding class’s name is based on the name of the xml file followed by the word Binding.

Answer (score 0):

When you have view binding enabled, for every layout XML you have, it'll generate a binding class named after it. So if you have `profile_activity.xml`, it'll generate a class called `ProfileActivityBinding`. An instance of that class will have a variable for each `View` in your layout that has an ID (named similarly, but it does some conversion from snake case - e.g. `my_button` will be called `myButton`)

You can get an instance of this class by either calling its `inflate` method, or the `bind` one. `inflate` will inflate the `profile_activity` XML file into a view hierarchy, `bind` allows you to pass in one that's already been inflated (e.g. an `Activity` or `Fragment`'s `view`).

You can use whichever one's convenient - if you need to inflate one anyway (say if you're creating a `ViewHolder` for a `RecyclerView`) you may as well use `inflate`. Otherwise `bind` will take an existing hierarchy and look up all the views it needs to. Either way, you end up with a variable for each ID in the layout, and each one points to the actual `View` in that hiearchy, as though it did `findViewById` for each one.

If all that makes sense, and it's still not working, try building your app (you can just do `Rebuild` in the Build menu). The binding classes *should* be automatically generated when you create a layout, and the code editor should recognise them pretty much immediately, but sometimes it needs a kick. Might need to do a Clean or Invalidate Caches / Restart if it's playing up

Comment: Thank you for the info, just a stupid syntax issue